# RestKit Conditional Mapping

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a Media model, and Image,Video and Audio models that inherit from media. 
I am using RestKit to map the data from an API(rails app).

Is there a way to do a conditional mapping using RestKit? If my response contains a media_type of video, then use the Video model mapping otherwise the image mapping etc.

**Update**

```
RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
RKObjectMapping *videoMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MMXMediaVideo class]];
RKObjectMapping *imageMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MMXMediaImage class]];
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"medium_type" expectedValue:@"video" objectMapping: videoMapping]];
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"medium_type" expectedValue:@"image" objectMapping:imageMapping]];
```

How do I add a mapping method to video or image mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configure your response descriptor with a dynamic mapping ([`RKDynamicMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html)). This mapping checks the incoming data to decide which mapping is the appropriate one to apply and returns that. The returned mapping is then used to perform the actual destination object creation and run the mapping procedure.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. To the dynamic mapping how do you associate another mapping? See updated section of my question.

Comment: Okay I found out the best way to do that ^. Thank you again.